# Where are in magento 1.8. core functions for sending emails?

Tags: php, magento, email

If I change or delete `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php` email still working and sending. I need modify that functions, but my modifications have not affect.

I uninstalled all the modules, there are no modules in `app/code/local`, `app/code/comunity`.

Cache deleting have no effect.

**Where else are or can be those functions?**

In 1.7. everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, problem was in Magento **compilation tool**.

Not only cache to show results, but needed to disable compiler too, eventually rename or delete ROOT/includes/ folder in Magento.

After that all new scripts should be available.